Как настроить VS code так чтобы браузер прочитывал изменения проекта
Есть у меня некоторый сайт и файл  server.py
Я подключил его к localhost командой  python server.py и вот беда. Раньше при перезагрузке страницы (на машине Ubunty) VS код при обновлении страниц сайта отправлял каждый раз свежую информацию, а сейчас нет. То есть я внёс изменения в js скрипты и хочу проверить функционал, но не могу так как в local хосте лежит старая версия что бы я не делал

это так заковыристо описан результат кэширования в http-клиенте/сервере?

Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Скорее всего, вам не нужно "управлять localhost". Вам нужно, чтобы браузер перечитывал изменения. Сам localhost при этом никак не меняется.

На убунту вы запускали тот же проект, или другой? Можете показать содержимое server.py?

Да проекты идентичны.

@enkryptor как прикрепить файл к платформе?

Если файл большой, выложите его текстом например на pastebin.com и дайте ссылку.

Вы пишете "код при обновлении страниц сайта отправлял каждый раз свежую информацию, а сейчас нет". То есть вы редактируете html и js файлы сайта, нажимаете F5 в браузере, и он показывает старое содержимое? Я правильно понял проблему?

@enkryptor ссылка: https://pastebin.com/cbGFA5Xy
Да, проблема в этом. Правда я нажимаю f12 и смотря на объекты вижу старую логику в js файлы, но вроде как вы примерно это и сказали

Первый комментатор был прав, проблема в кэше. Как только я отключил кэширование для этой страницы, все изменения стали отображаться.
F12 -> Network -> Disable Cache (галочка)

